# How to capture XML message from a request sent from SOAPui to Wiremock Server to compare against an XSD file

Tags: java, xml, wiremock

I need to capture an XML message that is sent as part of a request from SOAPui to Wiremock Server. Upon capturing this file, I would then need to compare it against an XSD file. The hard bit is capturing the XML file, I'm not sure what methods wiremock server has that would enable this.

For example, this is the XML message I want to capture in my java application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

What would I need to capture this?

Comment: Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to improve yours. Look for a good JAXB tutorial to learn how to handle xml with Java. Good luck!